# Resizing image on the fly

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess. All is working fine. Except there is a problem with this part:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule pic/(.*)--(\d+)*.(jpe?g|JPE?G|gif|GIF|png|PNG)?$ index.php/image/getinsize/?p=pic/$1\.$3&s=$2 [QSL,NS,L]
```

This creates resized image on the fly for example from:
/pic/posts/2015-12/43242/gals/picture.jpg
and stores it as:
/pic/posts/2015-12/43242/gals/picture--900.jpg

Image is saved on hdd and served by Apache. Problem is when next time the same image is requested, instead of serving already resized image, server is resizing and overiding it. Any idea why the !-f doesn't work?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule static\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)$ static/$1/$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule static/help/bg\/(.*)\/?$ /static/help/bg/item.php?l=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (lng_[^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/$2/$3?lng=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule news\/([0-9]+)\/([^/]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ /index.php/posts/post/?id=$1&pagenum=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule news\/([0-9]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/posts/post/?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule polls\/([0-9]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/polls/poll/?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule pic/(.*)--(\d+)*.(jpe?g|JPE?G|gif|GIF|png|PNG)?$ index.php/image/getinsize/?p=pic/$1\.$3&s=$2 [QSL,NS,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule pic\/(.*)--(pdf)(\d+)*\.(jpe?g|JPE?G|gif|GIF|png|PNG)?$ /index.php/image/getinsizefrompdf/?p=pic/$1\.$4&s=$3&f=$2 [QSD,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/$1/$2/$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (lng_[^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/$2/$3/$4?lng=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^feed/?$ /index.php/index/rss [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /index.php/index/sitemapxml [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ /index.php/pages/page/?url=$1&pagenum=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/pages/page/?lang=$1&url=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/$1/$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\/?$ /index.php/pages/page/?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Most likely because the image is not saved at the location you expect. Either a wrong folder or a wrong name.

Comment: For example: I fail to understand how that `RewriteCond` should match a file name, considering the different naming options you try to detect using the regular expression... I expect you save each image only once, not for example all permutations of upper and lowercase "file name extensions"...

Comment: Anyway, the more flexible and more robust approach here would be to _always_ use the routing script and implement a login in that router which checks if a previously generated image already exists. That gives you _much_ more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha! It is about pictures uploaded from users. They can be lower ot uppercase. So and the resized otput image.

Comment: Sure, still what I wrote stands. Maybe did not understand the point I raised.